# Is speech recognition possible in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, speech-recognition

Is it possible to do speech recognition in VB.NET?

Comment: Dear Aunt, let's set so double the killer delete select all.

Comment: 35 questions and 0 answers accepted. Wonderful :)

Comment: LOL @Johannes.  I should answer like that every time a business user asks me if something's possible.  User: "Can you do X..?"  Me: "Well, the language is turing-complete..."

Comment: @Dave: Well, for businesses the answer usually is “How much are you willing to pay?” :)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's SAPI is a speech recognition object you can use in .net code:

http://www.microsoft.com/speech

Any good?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the MSDN documentation on System.Speech.Recognition namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx

Thomas